# How to Create a Subscribeable News Feed?

Tags: php

I am working on a subscribeable feed for my WP site, but I have little knowledge in PHP/storing items in a database.

Here is what I need it to do:

-You register for an account and you are taken to the subscribe to feed page (done)

-On this page you can select between a few options of feeds you'd like to subscribe to. Each feed is a post category.

-When you go to the feed page, it will show all the articles that specific user has chosen to subscribe to.

The main things I'm lost on are saving data for each specific user and creating the form to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code, it makes helping you much easier.

Comment: Well, you know that WordPress automatically generates feeds for nearly everything, do you? Why should I subscribe to your service then?

Comment: I work for a Diocese. This is needed so we can produce a feed where users can subscribe to the websites of different parishes of their choosing.